# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "search" (type string) at path "_id" for model "PostMessage"

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

Getting cast error while performing query search in mongoose

```
export const getPostsBySearch = async (req, res) => {
    const {searchQuery, tags} = req.query
    try {
        const title = new RegExp(searchQuery, 'i')
        const posts = await PostMessage.find({ $or: [{ title: String(title) }, {tags: {$in: tags.split(',')}}] })
        res.json({data: posts})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(404).json({message: error.message})
    }
}
```

invoking it

getPostBySearch({search: 'none', tags: 'wonders'})

i am expecting a array of post with associated filters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be the problem of how you arrange your routes in your server-side code.

You may refer to [here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/frameworks/dist/Cast+to+ObjectId+failed+for+value+%22t%22+at+path+%22_id%22+for+model+%22User%22).

In my case I simply rearrange the routers from

```
router.get("/", getPosts);
router.get("/:id", auth, getPost);
router.get("/search", getPostsBySearch);
```

to

```
router.get("/search", getPostsBySearch);
router.get("/", getPosts);
router.get("/:id", auth, getPost); # routes with id need to come after other routes
```

Hope this can help!

Answer (score 0):

**Error message**:
*{"message":"Cast to ObjectId failed for value "search" (type string) at path "_id" for model "PostMessage""}*

**Just change and re-arrange the router setup:**

**Before:**

```
router.get('/', getPosts)
router.get('/:id', getPost)
router.get('/search', getPostsBySearch)
```

**After:**

```
router.get('/', getPosts)
router.get('/search', getPostsBySearch)
router.get('/:id', getPost)
```

For me, this is working. Re-arrange your router setup and check again.